# Excel Count Formula

Tags: excel

I have excel data file like:

[image: Excel Data File]

How can I count Yes/No Row # 2 to 6 then Row # 7 to 11 and Row # 12 to 20?

Pls. suggest if possible in excel.

Comment: Is there any logic for the highlighted values in colum A?

Comment: Yes, the group head and the same value as in Column D

Answer (score 0):

Use the function COUNTIF instead of COUNT

COUNTIF basically returns a count value of the cells that meet a certain criterion provided by you

Syntax: =COUNTIF(Where do you want to look?, What do you want to look for?)

Eg) `=COUNTIF(C2:C6,"Yes")`

If you need further help, you can look it up in the Microsoft documentation, link below:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34

Answer (score 0):

You need a helper column that calculates the A-value per row.

Then you can count the yes and nos

Formula for helper column:
`=IFNA(INDEX(tblAggregate[Aggregate],MATCH([@Key],tblAggregate[Aggregate],0)),C3)`

This formula searches the aggreagte term, if it is found it is put in the helper column, if not (`ISNA`) then the value from the cell above is used.

Formula to count yes or no:
`=COUNTIFS(tblData[Value],F$3,tblData[helper column],[@Aggregate])`

A simple `COUNTIFS` that takes the condition for yes or no from the header = F$3

[image]